# MYSQL DATE_SUB not working correctly

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to return all rows created within the last 10 seconds, ie where "date_created" < 10 seconds old. Here's the sql I'm using, but this doesn't seem to work:

`SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM  tablename WHERE  date_created>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)`

...can anybody help me out?

Much appreciated.

Comment: can you explain better what doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Yep, it seems that all the results are seen as younger than 10 seconds, even ones created over an hour ago. I thought maybe ">=" should be "<" but that doesn't seem to be the case with all the other examples I've looked at.

Comment: Are your `date_created` values correct? And when just print `NOW()`, does it show the current time?

Comment: Yes, I just posted another a few minutes ago and it stored as 2015-11-05 15:19:22 (uk based server)

Comment: If you want `date_created` to be `<` than something then don't write `date_created >=`... :-?

Comment: I'm trying to say "where date_created is younger than 10 seconds old". Am I writing it incorrectly?

Comment: U can use TIMESTAMPDIFF . It will be like .. SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM  tablename WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_created, NOW()) < 10;

Comment: Thanks - I had the same problem with this too....but I know why...I'll post below...and I'm an idiot

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the date_created column is set as TIMESTAMP and not DATETIME - otherwise the calculation won't work correctly.

long day.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why do you think date calculations do not work with all date types? It's like claiming that you can multiply integers but not floats :-?

Answer (score -1):

The only flaw in your query is that it returns elements in the future:

```
mysql> create table tablename(
    ->  date_created datetime
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into tablename (date_created) values
    -> ('2000-02-29 15:00:00'),
    -> (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    -> (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval 5 second),
    -> (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval 11 second),
    -> ('2022-08-14 12:00:00');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select date_created,
    -> case
    ->   when date_created>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
    ->   then 'Matches'
    ->   else 'Does not match'
    -> end as 'Match'
    -> from tablename;
+---------------------+----------------+
| date_created        | Match          |
+---------------------+----------------+
| 2000-02-29 15:00:00 | Does not match |
| 2015-11-06 11:44:17 | Matches        |
| 2015-11-06 11:44:12 | Matches        |
| 2015-11-06 11:44:06 | Does not match |
| 2022-08-14 12:00:00 | Matches        | <==== This is not correct
+---------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just append the corresponding restriction:

```
AND date_created<=NOW()
```